# Connection refused in remote connection to InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, portforwarding

I have a running Influxd server on an Xubuntu machine and I want to make queries from another (Ubuntu) computer through internet (so, client and server are in different LAN).
I setup authentication on influxdb and portforward `port 8086` on my router, but I cannot access to server.

**input**:

```
curl -G http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8086/query -u admin:admin --data-urlencode "q=SHOW DATABASES"
(xx.xxx.xx.xxx is the server public ip address)
```

**output**:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xx.xxx.xx.xxx port 8086: Connection refused
```

The same curl query, if run on server with `localhost` instead of `xx.xxx.xx.xxx` return the correct results.

**output**:

```
{
  "results":[{
      "statement_id":0,
      "series":[{
          "name":"databases",
          "columns":["name"],
          "values":[["_internal"],["test"]]
      }]
  }]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?